# I want to make a simplified Java game engine

Tags: java, lua

I want to make a Java game engine that would be simple to use mainly for it would have a higher level language interpreter. I though about using Lua language with the LuaJ intertpreter, but I've got some really slow results...

I need suggestions for what other Lua-like languages (With a Java interpreter available) exist that (with an interpreter) could execute faster (than [LuaJ](http://luaj.org/luaj/README.html)) on my Java application.

Comment: we need a bit more information as to what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the domain of game programming, Java itself is considered slow. I would suggest that you can start with code generation facility built on top of Java. I have worked extensively on Drools , Groovy and similar DSLs and can vouch they are "slow" for even a typical enterprise app. One problem is the dynamic interpretation layer built over java. You can see the typical performances in this comparison study at http://www.slideshare.net/michael.galpin/performance-comparisons-of-dynamic-languages-on-the-java-virtual-machine

If you can work on creating a language which generates code before compiling, you will get best of both world. This doesn't mean you will need to know compiler theory stuff from day one. You can simply create utility functions in Java which you can distribute as client library. However, you will need to know Reflections thoroughly to approach the solution in this way. As *nobody* changes the code in a running production server, you will be perfectly fine.